# Is software identification based on icon on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is a very similar question to [Is software identification on-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic), but it's not identical.

I have recently been watching some screencasts, in which the caster has quite a few interested menu bar applications on OS X. I am curious as to what they are, but only have a small, simple icon to go by.

**Would the posting of a picture of an icon and asking for that (or similar) software be on-topic on this site?**

Answer (score 7):

If your question is “what software has this icon?” then, [going by the reasoning in the previous thread](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/818/is-software-identification-on-topic/820#820), no, it's off-topic. This isn't an icon identification site, this is a site where we recommend software to accomplish a task.

If the question is “what software was used in this video?”, then it might be on-topic, if you describe what the software was used for, what aspects of interface you liked, etc. A necessary condition to make the question on-topic is that if someone suggests software with similar functionality, it should still be a valid answer. For example, a functionally identical clone with different branding would be a valid answer. The icon could thus be an extra clue, but it cannot be a key requirement of the question.